# Usage of ember generate command for addon

Tags: javascript, ember.js, npm, ember-cli

I have my Ember engine/addon which has package.json as below;

```
{
  "name": "my-addon-ui",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "test-addon": "http://example.com/test-addon-1.1.1.tgz",
  }  
}
```

Also the package.json of the dependency test-addon looks like below;

```
{
  "name": "test-addon",
  "ember-addon": {
  },
  "keywords": [
    "ember-addon",
    "blueprint",
    "test-addon"
  ]
}
```

Now I see the following commands are used;

```
npm install
ember generate test-addon
```

While I understand what npm install does, I am confused about the usage of ember generate test-addon

What does it do exactly ? Does it map to the entries specified in keywords of "test-addon" ?

I am confused with the usage of ember generate without the type like

```
ember generate route OR
ember generate controller
```

Answer (score 1):

**Ember Generate** is an Ember-CLI tool to help you quickly generate boilerplate (AKA redundant) code for your Ember application. You typically use `ember g` for routes, controllers, helpers, or some other common building blocks of Ember.

However, you also have the ability to create your own "blueprints". "test-addon" is not included in your ember application by default. When you call `ember g test-addon`, you are creating boilerplate code for that specific addon.

When you call `ember generate test-addon`, Ember looks for a blueprint for the node-module `test-addon`.

Likewise, when you call `ember generate blueprint example-blueprint`, you are writing your own blueprint to be used by someone else.

https://ember-cli.com/generators-and-blueprints

Comment: Thx a lot...So I do see "blueprints" inside my node_modules/test-addon. But I am still confused. Does ember generate test-addon use that in any way OR is that generated because of ember generate test-addon command

Comment: Also in the documentation I saw 2 params passed as ; ember generate blueprint example-blueprint

But in my case, it is a single parameter. So how does that work ?

Comment: For your first question, I'm pretty sure `ember generate test-addon` does use the node_module/blueprints to generate a test-addon (I'm not sure what else it could use). For the second question, you are generating your own blueprint and calling it `example-blueprint`. Call `ember generate blueprints test-addon` in one of your projects to see it for yourself.